# Creating function to replace values in data frame

Tags: r

I have a big massive of data. Some columns contain categories of the data. For example "Month" or "Type of the room". To find the correlation I decided change data from text format to numbers. For example: January -> 01, February -> 02 etc
But some parts of data have too many unique variable and do it manually - not interesting.
I was trying to create loop to solve this issue, but can't build the logic:

I tried do this, but without success on the last step.

1. Searching unique variable in column
2. Sort them
3. Using current index after sort to replace this index for all variables in the column.

**The main goal:** analyze data and finding correlation between of them. I was trying to find any solution how to work with non-numeric data in correlation functions but without success

```
> massive.room.pr
   [1] "C" "C" "C" "A" "A" "A" "C" "C" "A" "D" "E" "D" "E" "G" "E" "E" "E" "E" "G" "G" "F"
  [22] "A" "A" "D" "I" "D" "D" "E" "A" "D" "A" "D" "E" "C" "D" "D" "C" "D" "D" "E" "G" "D"
  [43] "F" "E" "A" "G" "A" "E" "B" "F" "D" "A" "D" "C" "H" "C" "H" "D" "G" "C" "G" "E" "F"
  [64] "C" "A" "H" "C" "D" "A" "A" "D" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "E" "A" "A" "D" "A" "A" "A" "A"
  [85] "E" "E" "F" "A" "C" "C" "C" "E" "C" "A" "A" "A" "F" "E" "D" "E" "C" "D" "F" "C" "E"
```

```
> sort(unique(df$assigned_room_type))
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "K" "L" "P"
```

```
> seq(sort(unique(df$assigned_room_type)))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

---

## Data in `dput` format

```
massive.room.pr <-
c("C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "D", "E", "D", 
"E", "G", "E", "E", "E", "E", "G", "G", "F", "A", "A", "D", "I", 
"D", "D", "E", "A", "D", "A", "D", "E", "C", "D", "D", "C", "D", 
"D", "E", "G", "D", "F", "E", "A", "G", "A", "E", "B", "F", "D", 
"A", "D", "C", "H", "C", "H", "D", "G", "C", "G", "E", "F", "C", 
"A", "H", "C", "D", "A", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", 
"A", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "F", "A", "C", "C", 
"C", "E", "C", "A", "A", "A", "F", "E", "D", "E", "C", "D", "F", 
"C", "E")
```

Comment: Can you just try `as.factor(massive.room.pr)`? Each letter would be a factor. Factors are stored as integers, and have labels associated with these unique integers.

Comment: I would go with @jpsmith's approach. But if you really want the values to just be numbers, you could try `rank(massive.room.pr, ties.method = "min")` or `dplyr::dense_rank(massive.room.pr)`.

Comment: Bear in mind that months are a circular variable, so you need to be very careful how you interpret correlations, which are designed for linear variables.